# Explanation of Django Table Relations and How they are Being Called

Tags: python, mysql, django, class, models

I'm fairly new to Django and am currently trying to go through and modify a preexisting website. I'm trying to understand the syntax involved with creating a chart based on certain parameters. Currently the site takes account types as an argument and spits out a plot of account values vs. years. As shown in the first picture: 
[Picture of Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUmcb.png)

The part of the code I'm confused about is here:

```
tag_ids = [56, 123, 15, 21, 82]
if categories_1:
    tag_ids = categories_1.split(',')

tags = []


funding_announced_min = minyear+'-01-01'
funding_announced_max = maxyear+'-12-31'

business_list = []
for d in tag_ids:
    tag1 = Tag_objs.objects.get(pk=int(d))
    tags.append(tag1)
    business_1 = tag1.buisiness.filter(
        company__founded_date__gte=funding_announced_min,
        company__founded_date__lte=funding_announced_max,
        entity_type=0,
        )
    business_list.append(business1)
```

`tag` is a table of account types, and my confusion comes from the b`usiness_1 = tag1.business.filter` section. What exactly is this doing?

I have a model called `biz` that looks like this:

```
class biz(Ent):  
founded_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
employee_amount = models.IntegerField('Number of Employees',blank=True, null=True)
employee_amount_range = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
biz_status = models.CharField(choices=BIZ_STATUS_CHOICES, max_length=32, default='operating', blank=True, null=True)
zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
funding_rounds = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
funding_total_usd = models.BigIntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
first_funding_on = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
last_funding_on = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
closed_on = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
employee_count_min = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
employee_count_max = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):  
    return self.name

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "business"
```

But the only instance where I can see `business` is being referenced by a model is here in the `verbose_name_plural`. Does `verbose_name_plural` mean I can call the table `biz` as "business"?. The `ent` class is here:

```
class Ent(models.Model):
name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=255, db_index=True) 
desc = models.TextField('Description')
image = models.ImageField('Logo Image', upload_to='biz', blank=True, null=True, default='biz/default-user110.jpg')
cover_image = models.ImageField('Cover Image', upload_to='biz', blank=True, null=True, help_text='1300 width by 300 height top cover image.')
tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,related_name='business', blank=True)
featured = models.BooleanField()
limited = models.BooleanField()
city = models.CharField(max_length=128) 
state_province = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True) 
region = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True) 
country = models.CharField(choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES, max_length=128)
entity_type = models.IntegerField(choices=ENTITY_TYPE_CHOICES)
elevator_pitch = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
logo_url = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
profile_image_url = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
primary_role = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
uuid = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
domain = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

def __str__(self):  
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):

    try:
        int(self.slug[-1:])
        if self.slug.replace('-', ' ').lower() == self.name.lower():
            return reverse('business:biz', kwargs={'slug':slugify(self.name)})
        self.slug=slugify(self.name+' '+str(self.pk))
        return reverse('business:biz', kwargs={'slug':slugify(self.name+' '+str(self.pk))})
    except ValueError:
        self.slug=slugify(self.name)
        return reverse('business:biz', kwargs={'slug':slugify(self.name)})
```

To my understanding the class `biz` is a type of the class `ent` and the line `business.filter` is sorting through the `ent` table that is created by the `ent` model. If someone could give me a brief explanation of the line in question and then how the tables are communicating I'd be super appreciative. I apologize if this is a little confusing, I'm new and this is my first post. I couldn't find anything else like it in previous searches.

Answer (score 0):

The Biz model inherits from Ent. Ent has a many-to-many relationship with the Tag_obj model, and defines the reverse accessor as `business`, which means that from a Tag you can access the related Biz objects using that name.

Answer (score 0):

`verbose_name_plural` is designed for the admin interface, not for ORM relationships.

Couple of high level advice on the structure:

1. Make biz have a reference to to `Ent` rather than inheriting from it. This is likely causing some of the confusion.
2. Constrain your `try/except` block in the `Ent.get_absolute_url` function to just do the slug parsing.
3. Push the url parsing in the aforementioned method (2) into it's own `clean` method.
4. Ensure your Pk field on `Ent` is cleaned before insertion; You have a SQL injection liability there.
5. For your url names `business:detail` is clearer and more conventional than `business:biz`
6. Your uuid field in `Ent.uuid` should have a `default=uuid.uuid4` argument to make your life easier. There's also a builtin django class if you're planning to just use postgres - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield